# shell script to backup system

Tags: bash, shell

I am saving the backup files in a file using the following format backup#01.tar.gz , backup#02.tar.gz ,etc..
but now I need to loop on the backup directory to find the biggest number and name the next file increment to it ex: backup#03.tar.gz 
any help ?

Comment: It sure is possible to do what you want, but how about using a file containing a timestamp in a sortable format (such as YYYY-MM-DD_HHhMM)?  This would sidestep the issue and provide additional information in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that requires no subshell or external program, does not parse `ls` output (which is not recommended), and should work with filenames containing spaces (or even newlines).  You can customize your prefix and extension.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/path/to/files"
prefix="backup#"
ext=".tar.gz"
max=1
for file in "$dir/$prefix"*
do
  [[ $file =~ /$prefix([0-9]+)$ext$ ]] || continue
  n="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  [[ $max -gt $n ]] || max=$((n+1))
done
printf -v newfilename "$prefix%04d$ext" "$max"
```

Comment: The current `printf` expression pads to a length of 4 `(backup#0001.tar.gz)` while the OP asked for padding to 2.

Comment: I actually changed it from 2 to 4, thinking it would be better (99 backups before exceeding the naming format does not seem like a lot).  `%02` instead of `%04` would bring it back to 2 digits.  The matching does not block at any specific length and numerical comparisons will disregard leading zeros, so this is only a cosmetic issue, and the naming will continue just fine beyond the number of digits in the `printf` formatting string.

Comment: Thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, of course, I am going to simply assume your script will be running somehow from the directory where these backups are, otherwise just adjust.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in `ls backup*tar.gz -r -1`; do
    echo "Last backup file found is $filename"
    last=`expr ${filename[@]:7:2}`
    next=`expr $last +  1`
    newname=`printf "backup#%02d.tar.gz" $next`
    echo "Next backup file should be $newname"
    break # important!!!
done
```

I wrote it such that it is self explanatory, so I am sure there's more efficient or compact ways to do the same, but this should help you adapt/insert it in your grander scheme of things.

So, to summarize the operations:

- list in reverse order all the files in the folder matching "backup*tar.gz"
- assign *filename* the name of one such files. The first one will be our latest existing backup.
- use a combination of **expr** and **array operations** to extract the number and convert to an integer, which represents the last backup number
- increase such integer value by one with **expr**
- use **printf** to format the new backup filename, including padding
- **IMPORTANT** break the loop, because we already know the first file in this loop is the latest backup file, so we can exit.

Of course, you could change the way *filename* is acquired.

For reference on **array operations** which can conveniently be applied to strings in bash, check http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

EDIT: after @Fred's valuable input, while sticking with using `ls` for sorting the files for me, the following doesn't spawn as many subshells, it uses bash own arithmetic and the quite useful `-v` option from `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in `ls backup*tar.gz -r -1`; do
    echo "Last backup file found is $filename"
    last="${filename[@]:7:2}"
    printf -v newname "backup#%02d.tar.gz" $((last+1))
    echo "Next backup file should be $newname"
    break # important!!!
done
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is not recommended (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You do not need a loop if you just want the first line of output (use `read` and a process substitution `<()`).  You also launch many subshells : while not wrong, it is not necessary, as you can use shell arithmetic, the `-v` option of printf, shell expansion/matching.

Comment: @Fred Great additions. Considering the OP has a fixed naming scheme, resorting to a very controlled `ls` parsing shouldn't be as bad as the most general case. Shell arithmetic is definitely something I'll add to my answer, as well and the new-to-me suggested `-v` option to `printf`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help